# .ToString Error (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors

For some reason, this is not working for me , and I'm not sure. I'm trying to make a Set Home Page button for my webbrowser, and this is the code to check if a page is set, and then goto the page:

```
    Dim HomepageInfo As String
    If IO.File.Exists(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData & "\Homepage.Info") = True Then
        HomepageInfo = IO.File.ReadAllText(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData & "\Homepage.Info")
        WebBrowser1.Url = HomepageInfo.ToString
    Else
        'Create a File with a Default Homepage (www.google.com)
        IO.File.WriteAllText(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData & "\Homepage.Info", "www.google.com")
    End If
```

And this is showing as an error: HomepageInfo.ToString, and the error is: "Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Uri'."

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How is `WebBrowser1` declared?

Answer (score 0):

[`WebBrowser.Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property accepts an uri object not a string:

> Property Value Type: System.Uri A Uri representing the URL of the
>   current document.

So you have to use an instance of [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class:

> Provides an object representation of a uniform resource identifier
>   (URI) and easy access to the parts of the URI.

Code:

```
Dim HomepageInfo As String
If IO.File.Exists(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData & "\Homepage.Info") = True Then
    HomepageInfo = IO.File.ReadAllText(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData & "\Homepage.Info")
    WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri(HomepageInfo.ToString)
Else
    'Create a File with a Default Homepage (www.google.com)
    IO.File.WriteAllText(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData & "\Homepage.Info", "www.google.com")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try have to use like this

```
WebBrowser1.Url = new Uri(HomepageInfo.ToString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple: Your WebBrowser1.Url is not a string, but an URL - an URL is NOT a string, but behaves idfferently, e.g. options for checking he validity of an URL.

You can construct a new URL to circumvent this problem:
WebBrowser1.Url = new Uri(HomepageInfo.ToString)

But this might fail, of the given string is not a valid URL.